# Cast to Type with reflection without generic argument

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection

I have an issue which involves casting to different Types

I have a class which is a wrapper, which contains an inner wrapper which contains `T` here is the structure:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public readonly Guid Foo;

    public Wrapper(Guid foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}

public class Wrapper<T> : Wrapper
{
    public readonly InnerWrapper<T> InnerWrapper;

    public Wrapper(Guid foo, InnerWrapper<T> innerWrapper) 
        : base(foo)
    {
        InnerWrapper = innerWrapper;
    }
}

public class InnerWrapper<T> 
{
    public readonly Guid Bar;
    public readonly T Content;
    public InnerWrapper(T content, Guid bar)
    {
        Content = content;
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

In another part of the code I have a `List<Wrapper>`. notice that is a list of wrapper not a list of `wrapper<T>` which means that T can be any class.
when this translates is expected to have something like

```
{
    wrapper<Class1>,
    wrapper<Class2>
}
```

and so on.

At some point in the code there is a "helper class" which contains the object as `object` type and the `Type`

```
public class Helper
{
    public readonly object Obj;
    public readonly Type Type;

    public Helper(object obj, Type type)
    {
        Obj = obj;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

And here is where my problem begins, I created a helper method to convert from `List<Helper>` to `List<Wrapper>` and it does it, but the inner object is type `object` instead of being the actual type.

And i have no clue of how to convert from `object` to the actual type without using generics, and as T can be multiples types I cannot use them.

This is the helper classs

```
public static class HelperExtensions
{
    public static T CastTo<T>(this object o) => (T)o;

    public static List<Wrapper> ToWrapper(this IEnumerable<Helper> helperList)
    {
        List<Wrapper> wrapperResponseList = new List<Wrapper>();
        foreach (var help in helperList)
        {
            // doesn't work either var typedValue = Convert.ChangeType(help.Obj, help.Type);

            var methodInfo = typeof(HelperExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(CastTo), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            var genericArguments = new[] { help.Type };
            var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo?.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments);
            var typedValue = genericMethodInfo?.Invoke(null, new[] { help.Obj });

            var wrapper = typedValue.BuildWrapper(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());

            wrapperResponseList.Add(wrapper);
        }

        return wrapperResponseList;
    }


    //This one called individually does the work properly
    public static Wrapper<T> BuildWrapper<T>(this T obj, Guid foo, Guid bar)
    {
        InnerWrapper<T> inner = new InnerWrapper<T>(obj, bar);
        return new Wrapper<T>(foo, inner);
    }

}
```

to show the code here I also Created a test class

```
public class Placeholder
{
    public Guid Value { get; }

    public Placeholder(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

so when I call

```
Placeholder placeholder = new Placeholder(Guid.NewGuid());
Helper helper1 = new Helper(placeholder, placeholder.GetType());
var result = new List<Helper> { helper1 }.ToWrapper();
```

It generates a `List<Wrapper>` but instead of `wrapper<T>` it is generating `Wrapper<Object>`

Any idea how can I cast it properly?

I also created a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/pz3JDz which contains all the needed code to test.

Thanks In advance for your help.

Comment: why don't you invoke directly `BuildWrapper<T>` as generic ? something like `typeof(HelperExtensions).GetMethod("BuildWrapper").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { help.Type}).Invoke(this,help.Obj)`

Comment: @Franck I didn't event think in that option; It worked.
Answer the question so I can give you the green tick :D, 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the call to directly retrieve the object from the `BuildWrapper<T>` is possible.
You can do the following. You can obviously reformat for error check but you get the idea.

```
var wrapperGeneric = typeof(HelperExtensions).GetMethod("BuildWrapper").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { help.Type}).Invoke(this,help.Obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

The local variable `typedValue` is declared with `var` and because `genericMethodInfo?.Invoke(...)` returns the reply of the type `object`, the type of that local variable `typedValue` will be `object`. After that you call the generic method  `Wrapper<T> BuildWrapper<T>(this T obj, ...)` here since the type of `typedValue` is `object` the type of `T` is will also be `object`, therefore it will return `Wrapper<object>`.

To solve it instead of this:

```
var wrapper = typedValue.BuildWrapper(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());
```

Do this:

```
var buildWrapperMethodInfo = typeof(HelperExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(BuildWrapper), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var buildWrapperGenericMethodInfo = buildWrapperMethodInfo?.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments);
var wrapper = buildWrapperGenericMethodInfo?.Invoke(null, new[] { typedValue, Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() });
```

And then add the type cast here:

```
wrapperResponseList.Add((Wrapper)wrapper);
```